# Theory for 3-bit full adder and calculations with un-/signed integers

Tags: digital-logic

With the following scheme, I built myself a 3-bit full adder. What I'm wondering is, and I couldn't figure this out myself, does the adder calculate with signed or unsigned values?

- Is the range for the 3-bit adder between (-4) and 3, or is it between 0 and 7?
- Alternatively, is it whatever. As in, can I choose whether I want the binary number 111 to represent (-1) or if I want it to represent 7?

The adder of course can make both addition and subtraction. The scheme I took came from [here](http://minnie.tuhs.org/CompArch/Tutes/week02.html). The site has a scheme with overflow and subtraction/addition added to the scheme.

The site claims: *"When is the result negative? When its most-significant bit is 1. "* But I'm still not sure if that must be the ABSOLUTE truth. I'm thinking the range (-4) and 3 is necessary to calculate with subtraction. Am I correct?

[image]

---

[Answer](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/courses/dig2/5_Adder.pdf) to my problem. The main reason we use 2s complement is in fact the advantage that we can display unsigned and signed integers on the **same** circuitry.

[image]

Comment: By the wa.y, you should self-answer your question by posting a separate answer. Answers don’t belong in questions. And yes, it’s fine and encouraged to self-answer if you find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be either. It will work with unsigned 3-bit numbers. It will also work with 2s complement signed numbers. You'll need to do a bit of study, but the thing to remember with 2s complement is that a 0 sign bit means positive, and a 1 means negative.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Found a good source that explained what I was wondering. I attached an explanation to future viewers of this thread. Thank you for your help :)